# Issue with compiling after deleting a dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, dataset

I deleted a dataset and now I am getting all sorts of errors.  This one is really tripping me up.  It comes up as 'disassembly' which I have no idea what that is and this is the message:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: activationContext
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=activationContext
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks.